# Python dendrogram there must be a k such that (k \choose 2)=n)

Tags: python, dendrogram

I've trying to make a dendrogram in Python that takes the median values of some data then allows me to calculate the Euclidean distance between the median values.
Some of my data end up as negative values so I have to get the absolute value & offset all of the medians.

It seems to work fine if I only have 3 values to compare but for some reason if I have 4, or 5 values it gives me an error of "there must be a k such that (k \choose 2)=n)" but if I have 6 values it gives me a dendrogram of the last 4 values only.

I'm using Python 3.7.1, does any one know if there is some kind of bug? Cause I can't understand my code works for 3 values, doesn't work for 4 or 5 values, & gives me dendrogram of the last 4 values if I have 6 values.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.cluster.hierarchy as shc

#Calculate the median values of each group & make an array
a=10
b=-2
c=5
d=2.1
data = np.array([a,b,c,d])

#Find the lowest value because you can't make a dendrogram with a negative number
low = np.min(data)

#Offset data by the absolute of the lowest value +1, cause a 0 value won't work on a dendrogram
offset = abs(low) + 1
offset_array = []

# v = value, add offset to all values & save as an array
for v in data:
    offset_array.append(v+offset)

#Make an array of the offset values to calculate distances
cluster = np.array(offset_array)

# Labels for each value
#headings = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

df = np.array(cluster)

#Size of figure (x, y)
plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
ax = plt.subplot()
#Change x axis range as required
dt = 0.01
ax.semilogx(dt, np.exp(dt))
plt.title('Gram positive distance')
plt.xlabel('Euclidean distance')

dend = shc.dendrogram(shc.linkage(df, metric='euclidean'),
                      orientation='left', leaf_font_size=8, labels=headings)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem was with the linkage function. For the linkage function: "a collection of m observation vectors in n dimensions may be passed as an m by n array."

So I made a new test variable by reshaping your df array:

> test = df.reshape(len(df),1)

And then passed this new variable into your dendrogram function:

> dend = shc.dendrogram(shc.linkage(test, metric='euclidean'),
>                         orientation='left', leaf_font_size=8, labels=headings)